# NSView setNeedsDisplay causing a performance hit even when draw rect is commented out

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, drawrect

I have a Cocoa app that draws a lot data to the main screen(31000 samples by about 315 channels) so we are being very studious about profiling and getting everything as efficient as possible. I have a window controller that when opened updates it's view every 2 seconds based on the data. I am using an NSTimer and specifying the view update method.

The problem I am having is every time the timer fires the method, the main display hiccups slightly. I thought it would just be a matter of optimizing the drawRect method in the view subclass, but when I could not find any specific area in the draw rect method where the performance was bad, I decided to try commenting out the contents of the drawRect method.

results:
If I comment out the contents of the drawRect method, I will still get a hiccup.
If I comment out the call to [view setNeedsDisply: YES] in the calling method, it resolves the hiccup.

What Ive Tried:
1)  I modified the method calls so that when the timer fired I was using performSelectorOnMainThread to call the view

2)  I then tried to use the main dispatch queue with async.

neither of these things worked.

There is some kind of lag happening here even when there is no drawing work to do.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First, you need to profile exactly what is taking the time. At a guess, assuming your view class doesn't need to display a focus ring, try overriding `+defaultFocusRingType` to return `NSFocusRingTypeNone`. You should definitely be setting `needsDisplay` on the main thread, but the easiest way is to simply schedule the timer on the main thread's run loop rather than shunting work to the main thread or queue each time it fires.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I also tried overriding the isOpaque and wantsDefaultClipping methods. This improved the performance enough so that what I was seeing in the profiler made more sense.